# requesting different paragraphs of the body part of different articles with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, tags

I need the body part of different articles on a page. They've been written in a section tag including several p tags for each paragraph. like:

```
<section class="...">
 <div>...</div>
 <figure>...</figure>
 <p id='...' class='...'></p>
 <p id='...' class='...'></p>
 <p id='...' class='...'></p>
</section>

<section class="...">
 <div>...</div>
 <figure>...</figure>
 <p id='...' class='...'></p>
 <p id='...' class='...'></p>
 <p id='...' class='...'></p>
</section>
```

If I use code below :

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('url')

all_bodies = soup.find_all('section')
for i in range(len(all_bodies)):
    print(all_bodies[i])
```

It returns the complete content of section and if I add p tag to find_all it returns each p tag as an element of the list, but I want whole p tags of a section in one list element.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<section class="...">
 <div>...</div>
 <figure>...</figure>
 <p id='...' class='...'>1</p>
 <p id='...' class='...'>2</p>
 <p id='...' class='...'>3</p>
</section>

<section class="...">
 <div>...</div>
 <figure>...</figure>
 <p id='...' class='...'>1</p>
 <p id='...' class='...'>2</p>
 <p id='...' class='...'>3</p>
</section>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

[e.select('p') for e in soup.select('section')]
```

**Output**

```
 [[<p class="..." id="...">1</p>,
  <p class="..." id="...">2</p>,
  <p class="..." id="...">3</p>],
 [<p class="..." id="...">1</p>,
  <p class="..." id="...">2</p>,
  <p class="..." id="...">3</p>]]
```

Comment: That provides all p tags as an element of a list, but I need whole p tags of a section as an element.